# 'run-python' failing on Emacs 24.3.1 for Windows, custom vendor-supplied Python2.6

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

I'm doing some work with a custom version of Python 2.6 on Windows, and would love to use emacs for this purpose. On more unixy platforms, I've never had any issue with the basic python-mode stuff, but now I'm encountering a problem when I try to use the <kbd>M-x</kbd> `run-python` command.

My custom Python is on the path (i.e. can type `python` from a windows command prompt and get the appropriate version). Unfortunately, I simply get the following error in my *Messages* buffer when attempting to start it with `run-python` from emacs:

```
apply: Spawning child process: invalid argument
```

Is anyone running a similar python config that can shed light on this? Happy to post any other config details as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Somewhat oddly, I don't get a debugger buffer for this error, just the terse thing in the \*Messages\* buffer. However, I know debug is turned on, because I *do* get the buffer when I do something like <kbd>M-x</kbd> `foo`

Comment: Oddly, this seems to do absolutely nothing. Calling run-python as per jjpe's instruction, and manually setting the python path seems to work. I'm going to chock this one up to emacs subtly reminding me why I don't normally work in Windows.

Comment: My problem was the space in "Program Files". I replaced it with "Progra~1" and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `C-u M-x run-python`, which gives you the option of selecting the path of the python binary you want to run.

Alternatively, if you would like to start it using Elisp, that can be achieved by calling `(run-python "/usr/bin/python3")` for python3, for example.

Comment: Yes, this did it. For some reason, run-python doesn't seem to respect the paths set in my init.el. Calling it manually like this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, when we use standard backward slashes in the init.el file (.emacs):
(`setq python-shell-interpreter "c:\myRoot\Proframs\Python33\python3.exe"`)

Emacs interprets this as:
`c:myRootProframsPython33python3.exe`

This what is the invalid argument I think.

Thus we can:
(`setq python-shell-interpreter "c:/myRoot/Proframs/Python33/python3.exe"`)

Now C-u M-x "run-python" works.