# How to make Anaconda python work in Emacs on Windows

Tags: python, windows, emacs, anaconda

So I installed Anaconda on my Windows 7 computer. Now how to get it up and running in Emacs? I tried calling `M-x run-python`. I get the wonderful error message:

> apply: Spawning child process: invalid argument

My python executable is on the path. I tried changing the variable `python-shell-interpreter` was looking for in case `"python"` needed to be `"python.exe"`. That had no effect. So what gives? What's the magic sauce for getting them talking?

I placed these lines of code in my .emacs but still get the same error above.

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:/Users/My User/Anaconda/python.exe")
(setq python-shell-virtualenv-path "C:/Users/My User/Anaconda/")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720845/run-python-failing-on-emacs-24-3-1-for-windows-custom-vendor-supplied-python2

Comment: Can you run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, try again, and add the resulting backtrace (if any) to your question?

Comment: I actually searched first and discovered the "potential duplicate". I couldn't get C-u M-x run-python to let me set a different path. However, just like in that post, toggle-debug-on-error doesn't show any lisp code errors, just the message in *Messages* shown above, presumably since its the external call (or C code) that fails, not any elisp.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get emacs to point to a different Python by treating it like a "virtualenv". So something like

```
(setq python-shell-virtualenv-path "/path/to/anaconda/")
```

should do it. If you want to use a conda environment, replace `/path/to/anaconda` with the path to the environment, like `/path/to/anaconda/envs/envname`.

You can also use `M-x customize` to modify `python-shell-virtualenv-path`.

Comment: Your error message ("invalid argument") might be a different issue then.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, the directory where python.exe resides, is in the PATH-variable.

If needed, edit in "Advanced System Settings/Environment Variables"

Commonly this holds "C:\Python27\python.exe"

With Anaconda for example the following works here:

"C:\Users\My-User-Name\Anaconda\Scripts\python.exe"

Comment: Anaconda is definitely in my $PATH as verified through examining from Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and discovered that Emacs can find Python if I install Anaconda in the root of the drive ("C:\Anaconda3\") instead of in my home path.  I tested both Anaconda 2 and 3.  This is what I have in my .emacs:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:/Anaconda3/python.exe")
```

I cannot explain why this works whereas installing in the "C:/Users/My User/" does not. This is the first time I experience Emacs as having trouble with the home path.

Hopes this works for you, and perhaps somebody else are able to explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Running emacs from the Anaconda Prompt works for me.